# Trying to work out how I can make a query to show records that is due after 21days

Tags: sql, oracle

/*10 All charges are due within 21 days after they had the consulation (Date consulted).
Write a query to show the Staff Id, Speciality Id, Speciality Name, Date Qualified and Valid Till Date for all specialities. 
Due Date will be calculated using the Date Consulted + 21*/

```
SQL> describ consultation
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CHRGCODE                                  NOT NULL CHAR(7)
 STAFFID                                            CHAR(2)
 DATECONSULTED                             NOT NULL DATE
 STARTTIME                                          NUMBER(4,2)
 PATIENTNO                                          CHAR(7)

SQL> describ staff_speciality
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)
```

---

```
SELECT staffid,consultation
        specid,
        SpecName,
        datequalified,
        validdate
FROM staff_speciality
WHERE datequalified >21 and validdate >21;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
select ss.STAFFID, ss.SPECID, ss.DATEQUALIFIED, ss.VALIDDATE, 
(c.DATECONSULTED + 21) due_date -- due date is dateconsulted + 21d 
from staff_speciality ss join consultation c on c.staffid = ss.staffid
where c.DATECONSULTED + 21 >= sysdate + 21 -- show only when due date = today + 21d or more 
;
```